# Cómo consigo el color de un pixel en un bitmap?

Tags: c#, bitmap

para una actividad escolar tengo que unir unos círculos, crear un grafo con ellos, pero hay obstáculos en la imagen, lo cual impediría que mis vértices se unan, este es el método que uso para unirlos es de Bresenham:

```
public void drawLine(Point frm, Point to, Bitmap bmp, Bitmap org){
        double m, m2;
        double b, b2;
        double x_act, x_act2;
        double y_act, y_act2;
        int incremento, incremento2;

        m = ((double)to.Y-(double)frm.Y)/((double)to.X-(double)frm.X);
        b = frm.Y-(m*frm.X);
        m2 = ((double)to.Y-(double)frm.Y)/((double)to.X-(double)frm.X);
        b2 = frm.Y-(m*frm.X);

        Color c, c2;
        if(m2<1 && m2>-1){
            if(frm.X<to.X)
                incremento2 = 1;
            else
                incremento2 = -1;
            x_act2 = frm.X;
            for(;x_act2 != to.X; x_act2 = x_act2 += incremento2){
                y_act2 = x_act2*m2+b2;
                //Bitmap original, donde solo hay negro(Vertices) y rojo o azul(Obstaculos)
                c = org.GetPixel((int)(Math.Round(x_act2)),(int)(Math.Round(y_act2)));
                 //Bitmap copia donde solo hay verde(Vertices encontrados) y rojo o azul(Obstaculos)
                c2 = bmp.GetPixel((int)(Math.Round(x_act2)),(int)(Math.Round(y_act2)));
                int r = c.R;
                int g = c.G;
                int bl = c.B;
                if(bandera == false){
                    if(r == 0)
                        if(g == 0)
                            if(bl == 0){

                    }else{
                        bandera = true;
                    }
                }
                if(bandera == true){
                    if(c.ToArgb() == Color.White.ToArgb()){

                    }else if(c2.ToArgb() == Color.DarkGreen.ToArgb()){

                    }else{
                        return;
                    }
                }

            }
        }else{
            if(frm.Y < to.Y)
                incremento2 = 1;
            else
                incremento2 = -1;
            y_act2 = frm.Y;
            for(;y_act2 != to.Y; y_act2 += incremento2){
                x_act2 = (y_act2-b2)/m2;
                try{
                    //Bitmap original, donde solo hay negro(Vertices) y rojo o azul(Obstaculos)
                    c = org.GetPixel((int)(Math.Round(x_act2)),(int)(Math.Round(y_act2)));
                    //Bitmap copia donde solo hay verde(Vertices encontrados) y rojo o azul(Obstaculos)
                    c2 = bmp.GetPixel((int)(Math.Round(x_act2)),(int)(Math.Round(y_act2)));
                    int r = c.R;
                    int g = c.G;
                    int bl = c.B;
                    //Mientras salgo del vetice, cuando salí (ya nos es negro mi pixel, levanto mi bandera
                    if(bandera == false){
                        if(r == 0)
                            if(g == 0)
                                if(bl == 0){

                        }else{
                            bandera = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if(bandera == true){
                        //Si el pixel es negro, o verde esta bien, sino me regreso
                        if(c.ToArgb() == Color.White.ToArgb()){

                        }else if(c2.ToArgb() == Color.DarkGreen.ToArgb()){

                        }else{
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                }catch(Exception ex){}
            }
        }//end else


        if(m<1 && m>-1){
            if(frm.X<to.X)
                incremento = 1;
            else
                incremento = -1;
            x_act = frm.X;
            for(;x_act != to.X; x_act = x_act += incremento){
                y_act = x_act*m+b;
                bmp.SetPixel((int)(Math.Round(x_act)),(int)(Math.Round(y_act)),Color.DarkViolet);
            }
        }else{
            if(frm.Y < to.Y)
                incremento = 1;
            else
                incremento = -1;
            y_act = frm.Y;
            for(;y_act!=to.Y; y_act += incremento){
                x_act = (y_act-b)/m;
                try{
                    bmp.SetPixel((int)(Math.Round(x_act)),(int)(Math.Round(y_act)),Color.DarkViolet);
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    //MessageBox.Show("Fallo");
                }
            }
        }//end else

    }
```

De cierta manera usando lo que esta comentado obtengo un resultado al deseado, no trazo aristas a dos vértices que tienen un obstáculo, pero intentando conseguir el argb de un pixel, no pasa lo mismo y de plano no se traza ni una arista.

En resumen lo que quiero es:
 Si el pixel es negro: bajar bandera
   Si el pixel es blanco: levantar bandera

Si el pixel es negro y la bandera esta arriba: rompo mi ciclo y dejo de escanear y continúo con el siguiente par de vértices

Si el pixel no es negro o blanco: rompo mi ciclo y dejo de escanear y continúo con el siguiente par de vértices

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo un `Bitmap mapa`.

Para obtener el color en cada pixel del bitmap utilizo el siguiente codigo:

```
Color color;
for (int j = 0; j < altura; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < anchura; i++)
    {                
        color = this.mapa.GetPixel(i, j);

        pixeles[i][j] = (color.R + color.G + color.B) / 3;
     }
 }
```

lo que estoy haciendo es, convirtiendo a gris la imagen actual. Uso color para obtener R, G y B del pixel actual.

Para saber si el pixel es negro o blanco puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
if(color.R == 255 && color.G == 255 && color.B == 255) //segun ocupes
{
    //Tu expresion aqui
    bandera = true;
}
```